# Use variable nav outside a function

Tags: javascript

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    var nav = this.responseText;
  }
};

-->use nav here<--
```

How can I use my variable nav outside this function without being undefined?

Comment: Just declare `var nav;` without assigning it, outside the function.  Where you assign it, remove `var` (just assign it).

Comment: Define it outside the function and set its value inside the function?  Though you'll also need to keep in mind the asynchronous nature of what you're doing.

Comment: Declare it in the global scope and when you update it's value inside of the function. The global value will be updated. Remember don't declare it at both places if you will declare the variable in both scope the local one will be updated.


    Example -

```var a;
function b() {
    a = 10; //Update it here
}

console.log(a); // 10 will be logged```

Comment: You most likely can't get the value when you'd need it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323